# Efficiently masking and reducing a large multidimensional array using values from another array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have a `xarray.DataArray` with two 3-dimensional (`time, y, x`) variables `a` and `b`:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Random data
a = np.random.rand(100, 3000, 3000).astype(np.float32)
b = np.random.rand(100, 3000, 3000).astype(np.float32)

# Create xarray.Dataset with two vars
ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars={
        "a": xr.DataArray(a, dims=("time", "y", "x")),
        "b": xr.DataArray(b, dims=("time", "y", "x")),
    }
)
```

I need to calculate the median value of my variable `a` across the `time` dimension when my variable `b` is between a min and a max threshold. These thresholds vary for each `x, y` pixel (i.e. they can be expressed as 2-dimensional (`x, y`) arrays):

```
random_vals = np.random.rand(1, 3000, 3000) / 10.0
min_threshold = 0.5 - random_vals
max_threshold = 0.5 + random_vals
```

Currently, I'm doing this by identifying pixels in `b` that are between my thresholds, using this boolean array to mask `a` using `xarray`'s `.where`, then finally calculating the median value of `a` along the `time` dimension:

```
b_within_threshold = (ds.b > min_threshold) & (ds.b < max_threshold)
ds.a.where(b_within_threshold).median(dim='time')
```

This works, but the challenge is that is is extremely slow: `7.97 s ± 0 ns per loop` for this example (my actual arrays can be far larger: e.g. `shape=(500, 5000, 5000)`). In my analysis, I need to do this calculation hundreds of times for different sets of min/max thresholds, for example:

```
for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 100):
    
    # Create thresholds
    random_vals = np.random.rand(1, 3000, 3000) / 10.0
    min_threshold = i - random_vals
    max_threshold = i + random_vals
    
    # Apply mask and compute median
    b_within_threshold = (ds.b > min_threshold) & (ds.b < max_threshold)
    ds.a.where(b_within_threshold).median(dim='time')
```

Is there a more efficient/faster way I could apply this kind of calculation to my data? I'm happy with either an `xarray`, `numpy` or `pandas` solution - the speed of my current approach is just impractical given the amount of data I need to process, even when attempting to parallelise my code using `multiprocessing` or `Dask`.

Comment: Perhaps give Dask a try: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/faster-pandas-dask/

Comment: Thankyou - we already use `Dask` for parallel processing, but the bottleneck here is the speed of the underlying processing above.

Comment: Is a numba based solution allowed?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the data? Are the thresholds somewhat regular, like in your example or can they have arbitrary values? What is the precision of the a and b-data. I'm asking because maybe there is the possibility for pre-computation or reusable information.

Comment: Do you need to find the exact median or is an estimate within a certain tolerance or probabilty sufficient.

Comment: What is the desired behavior if all values along "time" are masked out by the threshold? I.e. what happens if you take the median over 0 values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The median is a rather expensive operation because it involves (partially) sorting a list and picking the middle value from it. Applying this operation along the time dimension, as you do, thus translates to sorting millions of (short-ish) lists hundreds of times. **This simply takes time.**

Your solution is already near-optimal on a python level, so your only two options are to either change your requirements or to optimize the constant overhead and parallelize. There are four things you can improve:

- If you can, choose `mean` over `median` because it is less expensive to compute.
- Use dask to parallelize the computation. You mentioned in a comment that you are already familiar with it, so I will not do this here.
- Compile your own kernel using numba or cython to avoid expensive intermediate copies.
- Ensure that your data is aligned/contiguous along the dimension you are computing. In this case `time`, so either switch to using fortran-ordered arrays or make time the last dimension of the array.

To make this concrete, here are the timings of your solution vs using your own (fortran-aligned) numba kernel:

```
Your Approach: 79.0010 s
Numba JIT: 7.7854 s
```

So about 10x faster. Keep in mind that these are single-core timings and that you will get further speedup from parallel processing. Here is the code for above timings:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from timeit import timeit
import numba as nb


def time_solution(solution, number=1):
    return timeit(
        f"{solution.__name__}(data, threshold_value, low, high)",
        setup=f"from __main__ import data, threshold_value, low, high, {solution.__name__}",
        number=number,
    )


def your_solution(data, threshold_value, low, high):
    ds = xr.Dataset(
        data_vars={
            "a": xr.DataArray(data, dims=("time", "y", "x")),
            "b": xr.DataArray(threshold_value, dims=("time", "y", "x")),
        }
    )

    result = ds.a.where((ds.b > low) & (ds.b < high)).median(dim="time")

    return result


@nb.jit(
    "float32[:, :](float32[::1, :, :], float32[::1, :, :], float32[::1, :, :], float32[::1, :, :])",
    nopython=True,
    nogil=True,
)
def numba_magic(data, threshold_value, low, high):
    output = np.empty(data.shape[1:], dtype=np.float32)

    for height in range(data.shape[1]):
        for width in range(data.shape[2]):
            threshold = threshold_value[:, height, width]
            mask = (low[:, height, width] < threshold) & (
                threshold < high[:, height, width]
            )
            buffer = np.where(mask, data[:, height, width], np.nan)
            output[height, width] = np.nanmedian(buffer)

    return output


# Time solutions
# ==============

shape = (100, 3000, 3000)
rng = np.random.default_rng()
data = rng.random(shape).astype(np.float32, order="F")
threshold_value = rng.random(shape).astype(np.float32, order="F")

random_vals = (rng.random(shape) / 10).astype(np.float32, order="F")
low = 0.5 - random_vals
high = 0.5 + random_vals


# assert equality of solutions
expected = np.asarray(your_solution(data, threshold_value, low, high))
actual_numba = numba_magic(data, threshold_value, low, high)
assert np.allclose(expected, actual_numba, equal_nan=True)

# compare timings of solutions
repeats = 10
print("""
Timings
-------""")
print(f"Your Approach: {time_solution(your_solution, repeats)/repeats:.4f} s")
print(f"Numba JIT: {time_solution(numba_magic, repeats)/repeats:.4f} s")
```

Answer (score 2):

- One improvement could be to sort the arrays on the time-dimension. That has a lot of upfront computational cost but only once at the beginning.
- After that you can continue the same way calculating the thresholds and masking the a-array.
- Then calculate the median not by calling the median-function but by directly accessing the middle element from the a-array (respectively the average of the two middle elements if the array-length is even).

```py
for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 100):
    # Create thresholds
    random_vals = np.random.rand(1, 3000, 3000) / 10.0
    min_threshold = i - random_vals
    max_threshold = i + random_vals

    # Apply mask and compute median
    b_within_threshold = (ds.b > min_threshold) & (ds.b < max_threshold)
    a_masked = ds.a.where(b_within_threshold)

    # Faster way to calculate median on a sorted array
    len_a_masked = len(a_masked)
    if len_a_masked == 0:
        median = None
    elif len_a_masked % 2 == 0:
        median = 0.5 * (a_masked[(len_a_masked - 1) // 2] + a_masked[len_a_masked // 2])
    else:
        median = a_masked[(len_a_masked - 1) // 2]
```

Depending on how many medians you are calculating this should be a significant improvement, as you have the additional cost of sorting the array only once, but the improvement from the faster calculation of the median for every threshold-iteration.